# Probles with mysql query selecting

Tags: php, mysql

Hello stackoverflow community. I need help with my script, ive got this mysql query:

```
    $AllTasks = mysql_query("SELECT task_id FROM dotp_tasks WHERE (task_type = '$key') AND (task_project = '$projectID') AND (task_id in (" . join(',',$UsrTasks) . ") AND (task_id in (" . join(',',$UsrTasks) . "))");
```

Problem is in the last parameters :

```
 AND (task_id in (" . join(',',$UsrTasks) . ") AND (task_id in (" . join(',',$UsrTasks) . "))
```

Somehow they dont want to be friends, here is how it looks like in Sublime:
[image]

Somehow it makes last AND colorless. What am i doing wrong, why they ain’t working together?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: echo out the string so we can see it un-complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice in your query you have the below condition repeated

```
AND (task_id in (" . join(',',$UsrTasks) . ") 
AND (task_id in (" . join(',',$UsrTasks) . "))
```

Again, in below line you are missing a `)` closing brace

```
AND (task_id in (" . join(',',$UsrTasks) . ")
```

Should be

```
AND (task_id in (" . join(',',$UsrTasks) . "))
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding single quotes to the last parameters as well:

```
$AllTasks = mysql_query("SELECT task_id FROM dotp_tasks WHERE (task_type = '$key')   
AND (task_project = '$projectID') AND (task_id in (" . join(',','$UsrTasks') . "))");
```

Answer (score 1):

Closing issue of `)`

```
AND (task_id in (" . join(',',$UsrTasks) . ")) AND (task_id in (" . join(',',$UsrTasks) . "))");
                                             ^^ // add this
```

So your whole query would be

```
$AllTasks = mysql_query("SELECT task_id FROM dotp_tasks WHERE (task_type = '$key') AND (task_project = '$projectID') AND (task_id in ('" . join(',',$UsrTasks) . "')) AND (task_id in ('" . join(',',$UsrTasks) . "'))");
```